# how to make navbar stretch across the page

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to add a navbar to my forum site and have a few issues.

1. the navbar/header is not exactly aligned/missing spaces between the other forum content.
2. when I scroll and the navbar hooks to the top the left side doesn't stretch out towards the left side only the right side.

example: [Example Gif](https://i.gyazo.com/ed8b82612c94c353a2abdf09012a0138.gif)

Here is the code I'm using

```html
 <div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">HOME</a>
  <a href="/news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="/forum">FORUM</a>
  <a href="/members">MEMBERS</a>
  <a href="/shop">SHOP</a>
</div>



<style>
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2b3c4e;
  z-index: 100; /* <-- Added */
  padding-left: 270px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>


<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your CSS like this. By making your a tags inline-block you can align them with `text-align:center`, you don't need padding-left. setting html,body and navbar width:100% makes it stretch the width of the page to handle your second problem. :

```
    html,body{width:100%; margin:0}

    #navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #2b3c4e;
      z-index: 100; /* <-- Added */
      text-align:center;
      width:100%;
    }

    #navbar a {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 25px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

Additionally, if you add this your header will go the width of the page on scrolling.

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
 }
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/cd8cvtbd/1/)

Comment: done the second part fixed the center part but the body part still doesn't stretch out  body {
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: is your #navbar contained in another container on your site? If so, set that container's width:100%, and make it's display:inline-block. If that doesn't help please post link to your site so I can take a look.

Comment: yes its in a container but the theme for it is disabled and its http://disorbs.net

Comment: Ok, any reason I cant use use html5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: hmm im not too sure

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it alone. This'll take a minute because of all the tables.

Comment: thanks man that sure fixed it now :) would you happen to know how to make the border fit more to the design so it doesn't show spaces?

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting my answer since it worked for you. Are you talking about the border in between the columns? If so, try .section-divider {width: 0px;}

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the padding-left in your CSS.

```html
 <div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">HOME</a>
  <a href="/news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="/forum">FORUM</a>
  <a href="/members">MEMBERS</a>
  <a href="/shop">SHOP</a>
</div>



<style>
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2b3c4e;
  z-index: 100; /* <-- Added */
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
</style>


<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: wont work that padding-left is to make the links centered without it they just move to the left but the stretch still doesn't happen.

Comment: you need to use text-align:center on the navbar, make your a tags inline-block and remove padding-left. see my answer below.